# Sample Trigger to Delete Task

Tags: apex

I have a Task being created automatically on Contact detail page whenever an email is fired to any contact.

I do not wish the task to be created for that e-mail.

Can we implement this using a trigger or any other way?

Comment: How are the `Task` records being *created* in the first place? It would be far better to alter that logic to never create them than to delete them after the fact.

Comment: The tasks are getting created from a managed package wherein bulk emails are send to the contacts based on some specific logic.

Comment: Do they expose any configuration options at all? It would be poor design if you couldn't control that behavior. What managed package is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the package allows you to configure this behavior. If you must delete them yourself, you could delete all `Task` records looking up to a `Contact` fairly easily in an `after insert` trigger.

```
public with sharing class TaskServices
{
    public static void cullUnwantedTasks(List<Task> tasks)
    {
        // call this method from your trigger
        List<Id> unwantedTaskIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Task task : tasks)
        {
            if (task.WhatId != null && task.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Contact.sObjectType)
            {
                // I would strongly recommend augmenting the above criteria
                // hopefully something uniquely identifies your tasks
                // e.g. as having originated from the managed package
                unwantedTaskIds.add(task.Id);
            }
        }
        Database.delete(unwantedTaskIds);
    }
}
```

Proper error handling is advised around the `delete` operation, but is ommitted for brevity. You will need to determine what behavior is "proper" in this case.